# My image disappears when I change the rotation CSS property

Tags: javascript, html, css, rotation

CODE:

```js
var img = document.getElementById("my_img")

window.onload = function(){
    img.style.transform = "translateX(100px) rotate(50deg)";
}
```

```css
#my_img img{
    transform: translateX(0px) rotate(0deg);
}
```

```html
<html>
<div id="my_img">
  <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/limav/flat-gradient-social/512/Stackoverflow-icon.png">
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

The image disappears, but when I enter the Chrome code editor (Ctrl+Shift+I), the image appears.

Comment: PS: I found that when i resize the window the image appears too. Is this a problem with my chrome browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, work in Chrome Version 81.0.4044.138

```js
const img = document.getElementById("my_img")
 const input = document.getElementById("rotate")
 const btn = document.getElementById("btn")

 btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  rotate(input.value);
 })

 function rotate(x) {
  img.style.transform = `translateX(100px) rotate(${x}deg)`
 }
```

```css
img {
     transform: translateX(0px) rotate(0deg);
 }
```

```html
<img id="my_img" width=100 height=100 src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/19/43/18/19431859261e12c5ba63da8f57b776ee.jpg">
<div style="margin-top: 50px">
 <input type="number" name="rotate" id="rotate" value="100">
 <button id="btn">Rotate</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by adding the class. I added setTimeout for demonstrate.

```js
var img = document.getElementById("my_img")

window.onload = function(){
    setTimeout(() => {
      img.classList.add("change")
    },1000);
}
```

```css
img{
    transform: translateX(0px) rotate(0deg);
}

.change {
  transform: translateX(100px) rotate(50deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
<img id="my_img" width=100 height=100 src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503023345310-bd7c1de61c7d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80">
</div>
```

Comment: But i'm coding something such that i need to change the rotation with javascript, i going to pass some variable as the angle. What can i do?